# Cannot resolve dependency to assembly error on xamarin forms wp8.1 compilation

Tags: .net, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working on the Xamarin forms application with the following details.(As part of maintenance).
Xamarin Forms version - 1.2.3.6257
Xamarin.Forms.labs - 1.2.0

With the above set of dll's i am not able to debug the windows application(wp8.1). But i am able to build the android application.

I am getting the below error.

> Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android,
>   Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it has
>   not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent
>   assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the
>   ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.

and in App.xml i am getting the error LocalizedStrings string does not exist in the namespace.

I tried upgrading Xamarin.Forms to 1.3.2.6316 and Xamarin.Form.labs 2.0.0.0. Still i am getting the same error.

Please someone could please explain me what i can do to resolve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using android platform specific APIs in shared project?

Comment: Yes i am using the platform specific API's.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use platform specific APIs in shared library. You can use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) instead.

Comment: Thank you. When I was searching over the internet I got the information like if Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.Labs are not compatible we will get the above error. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the WP project is referencing the correct Xlabs dll. If so, look in the [diagnostic build log](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) to see why the Android dll is being referenced. [Xamarin.Forms v1.2.3.6257](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/1.2.3.6257) is quite old (October 2014); the latest stable is [v2.3.3.180](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/2.3.3.180). XLabs has also likely seen a few updates since then, so it might be a good idea to check dependencies and update to the newer versions.